Let $X \sim N(0, \Sigma)$. Show that $X$ is sub-gaussian with the subgaussian parameter $\sigma = \max_{i=1, \ldots, n} \Sigma_{ii}$
To be more precise, let $X = (X_1, \ldots, X_n) \sim N(0, \Sigma)$.  Let $\sigma^2 = \max_{i=1, \ldots, n} E X_i^2 =  \max_{i=1, \ldots, n} \Sigma_{ii}$.
Let $Z = \max_{i=1,\ldots, n} X_i$. I want to show that
$$P(Z -EZ \geq t) \leq \exp(-t^2/2\sigma^2)$$ for all $t>0$.
My attempt:
It suffices to show $P(Z \geq t) \leq \exp(-c t^2/ \sigma^2)$ for some constant $c$(Let us not worry about the answer being off by a constant factor)
The most obvious try was the union bound of $P(Z \geq t) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n P(X_i \geq t)$. I've also tried with an additional assumption of independence and tried writing $P(Z >t) = 1- \prod_{i=1}^n P(X_i \leq t) \leq 1- (\Phi(t/\sigma))^n$, but this didn't work either.
Thank you.


Notice that the function $f(X_1/\Sigma_{11},X_2/\Sigma_{22},\dots,X_n/\Sigma_{nn})=\max(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)$ is a $\sigma$-Lipshitz function for these random variables, and $X_1/\Sigma_{11},X_2/\Sigma_{22},\dots,X_n/\Sigma_{nn}$ are i.i.d. $\mathcal N(0,1)$. Then, by Theorem 5.6 in Boucheron's Book, it is clear to have the bound.

Theorem 5.6 (Gaussian concentration inequality.) Let $X = (X_1,\dots,X_n)$  be
a vector of $n$ independent standard normal random variables. Let $f : \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ denote an $L$-Lipschitz function. Then, for all $t > 0$,  $\mathbb P (f(X)-\mathbb Ef(X)>t)\ge e^{-t^2/(2L^2)}$

The book's name: Boucheron, Stéphane, Gábor Lugosi, and Pascal Massart, Concentration Inequalities: A Nonasymptotic Theory of Independence (Oxford, 2013; online edn, Oxford Academic, 23 May 2013)
It is on Page 123, proved as a corollary as a consequence of the Log-Sobolev inequalities.
Link: https://www.hse.ru/data/2016/11/24/1113029206/Concentration%20inequalities.pdf
